# How can I tell if a table is saved as parquet files?

Tags: hive, parquet, file-format, hive-metastore

I am using HiveMetaStoreClient to get some meta data of hive tables and I got some tables saved as parquet while other tables saved as text. For tables saved as parquet, I want to get some more information like parquet schema.

So how can I get the file format of a hive table via HiveMetaStoreClient? Or if there is any other interfaces to do that?

I am thinking maybe I can try to read each table with ParquetReader and catch exceptions. Like:

```
try {
    metaData = ParquetFileReader.readFooter(conf, file, NO_FILTER);
    MessageType schema = metaData.getFileMetaData().getSchema();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Not parquet!!!")
}
```

But it is like the worst choice.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options.

1. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`
2. Use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED <tablename>`
3. You can use **hue** which offers web GUI to Hadoop users.
4. If you have set up namenode for UI too, you can access the details or even browser the files. The url is generally http://:50070. It does not show a lot of details about the table. It is used for overall hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by running "SHOW CREATE TABLE " in a Hive session and in the result you will see the CREATE statement of this table with file format details in it. It would look something like the below,

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

Let me know if thats what you are looking for!